# Trouble sending messages from event hub processor to SignalR service bus backplane

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-eventhub, signalr-backplane

I am using SignalR with a service bus backplane. Trying to initiate messages from something that isn't a webserver. (Event hub processor)

The following code works fine in a C# command line app.

```
string conn = ""
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(conn, "MY_PREFIX");
var server = TestServer.Create(app =>
{
   app.MapSignalR();
});
...
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ExampleHub>();
hubContext.Clients.Group("MyGroupName").broadcastMessage("Test");
...
```

But when added to the event processor code, it is silently not sending the data.
My question is, how can I set this up to work in an event hub processor.

I am currently working around this issue by sending a web request to the website that then broadcasts the message.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe turn on tracing in (web|app).config for more debugging info.

Comment: If you think the problem is with your usage of EventProcessor I would suggest showing that part.

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue?